# Arithmetic speed distance and time

Tags: arithmetic

What if the time of departure is 12:15 and time of arrival is 14:45, it’s asking me to find the distance travelled.

Comment: Distance traveled has to be in km if that helps

Comment: Hey Baek, and welcome to Math SE, unfortunately your question is not very clear, you will benefit of having a clearly posed question. As it is right now, your post can mean a whole lot of different things. Please consider editing your question

Comment: I apologise let me rephrase. The chapter is average rates of change (with respect to time) and the question is all in a box with a couple blanks. It’s given me a time of departure=12:15 and a time of arrival=14:45 and the two blanks are distance travelled(km) and average speed. I know how to calculate the average speed but I need the distance travelled to calculate it. My question is how do I calculate it?

Comment: If you don't have any distance, or velocity, there's not much you can do

Comment: That’s okay I’ll just write something down and skip it

Answer (score 1):

You travelled $7.5$ miles, walking at a constant speed of three miles per hour.

Or, you travelled $500$ miles on a high-speed train going $200$ miles per hour.

Or, you travelled $50$ miles going $20$ miles per hour on horseback.

Or ...